# Single word for a person who puts forth effort only in front of management

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to find a single word/term for an individual that puts forth effort only when being observed by management. All other times individual is lazy/useless, but everything changes when the boss is around! Is there a term for this?
Thanks!

Comment: I can think of a number of words to use for such a person, although not in the way you mean.

Comment: looking a google results there a numerous tips and tricks to do exactly what you describe.

Comment: Brown-nose is used a lot but I don't think it defines this very specific habit.

Comment: Ass-kisser seems like a common term, but I know I've heard something better ...

Answer (score 2):

The term for the phenomenon, when you perform better under observation, is ***Hawthorne effect***:

> (also referred to as the ***observer effect***) is a type of reactivity in which individuals modify or improve an aspect of their behavior in response to their awareness of being observed. *[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawthorne_effect)*

I don't believe there is a succinct single word to define a person who is a slacker but pretends to work hard when the boss is watching. *Sycophant* and related adjectives come to mind but they are not specific enough.

Comment: Here is an article titled: [The Hawthorne Effect (work faster, the boss is watching!)](http://www.20dollareval.com/2012/12/11/the-hawthorne-effect/)

Comment: Yes, the effect is known. That's one of the first things that come up in google, but I'm looking for a term defining something completely different - the conscious "show-off" type thing that a slacker would do when observed by someone higher up.

Comment: @WalterChristie: I wouldn't say *Hawthorne effect* is completely different. It is closely related and I even gave an article that uses the phrase "boss is watching" along with "hawthorne effect". I believe this phenomenon covers the situation except the employee might not be a slacker. However, you are asking for a very specific term that I don't think it exists. Do you think general adjectives like sycophant and its synonyms cover it?

Answer (score 1):

If you look up synonyms for *[phony](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/phony)*, you will find

> *dissembler, dissimulator, hypocrite, phoney, pretender, whited sepulcher. beguiler, cheater, deceiver, trickster, Tartuffe*

*thefreedictionary.com*

Comment: "dissimulator" is an interesting word I did not know, not sure if there is a specific work or effort connotation though.

Comment: None of these terms are specifically work related, and they are often applied to other spheres. You could craft a phrase like *closet shirker* which would convey an avoidance of effort.

Answer (score 0):

A good hyphenated word for the person you describe is *man-pleaser*. A man- pleaser is exactly the kind of person you describe. He or she

> - puts forth an effort only when management is present
> - slacks off when management is not present
> - snaps to attention the moment management is present once again

The kind of "work" this person performs could be called "eye-service." In other words, he performs only when management has their eye on him.

A true test of character is whether you work just as hard and conscientiously when you're being observed as when you are not being observed. A man-pleaser would most definitely fail this test!

Answer (score 0):

*suck-up* and *brown-noser* are specific, but not too polite.

*opportunist* is general, but covers this.

Answer (score -1):

**Kiss ass**

[Urban Free Dictionary]:

A person who will go to many lengths to impress to look impressive, good, and worthy towards persons or groups of higher social standing. This is usually done to ascend in their workplace. In their attempts for higher status and privilege, they will become unguarded and their peers will notice how fake and transparent their attempts are.

Synonyms include brown-noser, yes man, bitch, suck up, teacher's pet, and butt kisser